# vba do loop - i don't know why it is stoping

Tags: excel, vba

```
  Do Until Not (ActiveCell.Offset(j, -2).value = ActiveCell.Offset(j - 1, -2).value)
      kwota = kwota + ActiveCell.Offset(j, -1).value
      j = j - 1
  Loop
```

When condition is false it is going to next loop but when it's true it stop and i must press ctrl+break, why?

Comment: "Do Until Not"? Isn't that not not not different to "Do While"? You should write your code as if your third-grade English teacher (the one who isn't shy of a little cane-based punishment) is standing right behind you :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
If ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).value = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, -2).value Then
      ActiveCell.Offset(0, 8).value = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 8).value
End If
```

This is a solution for my problem, it's working great :)